# Buddypress – Comment date showing in “replied 01.January.1970, right now

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am using Buddypress in my wordpress website. I have one issue with date. When I am commenting on any topic then after loading date being showing in following format -

"replied 01.January.1970, right now" .

[Question Image http://www.dataflakes.com/testabc/askamet/img/questionimage.png](http://www.dataflakes.com/testabc/askamet/img/questionimage.png)

But when I refresh the page then it shows correct date and time.

Wordpress version - 4.1.8
BuddyPress Version - 2.2.1

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That date is the start of time ('strtotime') in PHP. So it would appear that WP/BP is not reading the actual time from the server when you are writing your comment. That's why it is displaying the default 'strtotime.'

But when you submit the comment and the page refreshes, it gets the actual time from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to edit the comment function so make sure it calls the WP function get_the_date()

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date

But I would first turn off all plugins except BPress and try a comment. Might be a conflict somewhere.